# Deletion of an element of an array

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num[20]={0};
  int n,j;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  scanf("%d",&num[j]);
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  printf("%d %u\n",num[j],&num[j]);
  for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    if(j>=2)
    num[j]=num[j+1];
  }
  for(j=0;j<20;j++){
    printf("    %d %u\n",num[j],&num[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Suppose I want to remove the 3rd element from the array.

```
/*  Let the input be :-
    4
    3 6 7 2
    And the output is :-
    3 4043267280
    6 4043267284
    7 4043267288
    2 4043267292
        3 4043267280
        6 4043267284
        2 4043267288
        0 4043267292
        0 4043267296
        0 4043267300
        0 4043267304
        0 4043267308
        0 4043267312
        0 4043267316
        0 4043267320
        0 4043267324
        0 4043267328
        0 4043267332
        0 4043267336
        0 4043267340
        0 4043267344
        0 4043267348
        0 4043267352
        0 4043267356 */
```

Where does the number 7 go ? It should be at memory location 4043267296 because I have only made changes for j<4. What is the logic behind this .

Comment: You _explicitly_ replace it, no? What's this code block`if(j>=2)num[j]=num[j+1];` doing?

Comment: You should indent your code properly. Poorly indented code is hard to understand, even for experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the number 7 go ?

You overwrite it with the value 2

First your `scanf` loop do:

```
num[0] = 3
num[1] = 6
num[2] = 7
num[3] = 2
```

Then this loop:

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    if(j>=2)
        num[j]=num[j+1];
}
```

will do:

```
num[2] = num[3] (which is num[2] = 2 overwriting the 7)
num[3] = num[4] (which is num[3] = 0 overwriting the 2)
```

> It should be at memory location 4043267296

No. 4043267296 is the location/address of `num[4]` and your code (with input `n=4`) only writes to `num[4]` during initialization. So 7 will not be at this address.

Answer (score 0):

When `j` reaches `2` which is the value of `num[2]` then `num[2]=num[3]` so `num[2]` will take the value of `num[3]` which is `2` and then your `7` disappears. You keep the same logic for the following elements.

**You cannot change the address of a variable**.